# Adding a feature that allows users to "follow" other accounts

Tags: discussion

There are a number of users on QC stack exchange that consistently give extremely thorough and impressive answers. I love reading these user's responses, even to questions I already know the answer to, because they both further solidify my own understanding and provide a great example of how to structure effective answers in the forum. One interesting feature could be the ability to track the activity of certain users with a separate feed that lists all the most recent questions/answers/comments from your favorite accounts. This could also be useful for users that want to be notified when a particular person asks a question. Does an idea like this seem interesting? Or does it distract from the purpose of the platform?

Comment: you might already know this, but you can also easily see other people's answers from their profile, e.g. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/13991/ryanhill1?tab=answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a duplicate of a question that's been asked many times on the Mother Meta: "[Is there a way to follow people's activity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18978/391772)" is an example, and itself is listed as a duplicate of other questions asked on Mother Meta.

The best solution I could find is this that you can subscribe to their RSS feed: `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/{insert-user-id-here}`

If you want this feature to be enhanced in anyway, posting on our (small) Meta site will not likely get you anywhere, since the QCSE moderators cannot implement this feature for us. The only people that can add this feature are Stack Exchange developers (employees that write the code for this website), and they will only do it if they are instructed to do so, which would usually only happen after someone like a Community Manager (also an employee of the Stack Exchange company) approves a feature request on the network-wide Mother Meta.